# Takes multiple clicks on a button

Tags: vb.net

I'm working my way through 200 short video tutorials on VB and in the one that deals with message boxes, the instructor asks us to try our hand at responding to a few more buttons with some Else If statements. I got it to work, kinda, except that I have to click on the Retry button twice before it will work and I have to click on the Ignore button three times before it will work. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? My code is below.

```
Private Sub btnShowMsg_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnShowMsg.Click

    If MessageBox.Show("Click Something", "Make a Selection", MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Abort Then
        MessageBox.Show("Hey, you Aborted me!")

    ElseIf MessageBox.Show("Click Something", "Make a Selection", MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Retry Then
        MessageBox.Show("You are trying to retry, aren't you?")

    ElseIf MessageBox.Show("Click Something", "Make a Selection", MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Ignore Then
        MessageBox.Show("Don't you dare ignore me!!")

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You should learn how to use the debugger to spot such issues :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understand that every time you call the `MessageBox.Show` Method a *new* `MessageBox` will be displayed and a *new* `DialogResult` will be returned.

In order to further simplify the logic, consider the following pseudocode:

```
If MessageBox.Show Result = Abort
    Show You Aborted Me
Else If MessageBox.Show Result = Retry
    Show You Clicked Retry
Else If MessageBox.Show.Result = Ignore
    Show You Ignored Me
```

If the user clicks anything other than "Abort" when the `MessageBox` is first presented, the runtime will begin to execute the second `If` statement which will present an identical but *new* `MessageBox` to the user.

This process repeats until the user either meets the  the condition of the `If` statement or there are no more `If` statements to consider.

In order to resolve the problem you should ensure that the `MessageBox` is only presented to the user once. Store the `DialogResult` in a local variable and then evaluate the `DialogResult`.

```
Dim result as DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Click Something", "Make a Selection", MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore, MessageBoxIcon.Question) 

If result = DialogResult.Abort Then
    MessageBox.Show("Hey, you Aborted me!")
ElseIf result = DialogResult.Retry Then
    MessageBox.Show("You are trying to retry, aren't you?")
ElseIf result = DialogResult.Ignore Then
    MessageBox.Show("Don't you dare ignore me!!")
Else 
    ' What are you going to do if the user never clicks an applicable button? 
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating three messages boxes (one on each `If`/`ElseIf` clause) in the worst case, while you should only create one message box.

Store the result of the message box first:

```
' create only one MessageBox and store the result '
Dim result = MessageBox.Show("Click Something", "Make a Selection", MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore, MessageBoxIcon.Question)

If result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Abort Then
    ...
ElseIf result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Retry Then
    ...
ElseIf ...
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are asking the question at every IF. You need to ask it once up front and store the resulting value OR you could do a case statement.

```
Dim result As Windows.Forms.DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Click Something", "Make a Selection", MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore, MessageBoxIcon.Question)

If result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Abort Then
    MessageBox.Show("Hey, you Aborted me!")
ElseIf result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Retry Then
    MessageBox.Show("You are trying to retry, aren't you?")
ElseIf result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Ignore Then
    MessageBox.Show("Don't you dare ignore me!!")
End If
```

OR

```
Select Case MessageBox.Show("Click Something", "Make a Selection", MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
    Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Abort
        MessageBox.Show("Hey, you Aborted me!")
    Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Retry
        MessageBox.Show("You are trying to retry, aren't you?")
    Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Ignore
        MessageBox.Show("Don't you dare ignore me!!")
End Select
```

Comment: There's no `switch` in VB.Net. You mean `Select`.

Comment: Same thing different syntax. :P

Comment: Not really. VB.Net's `Select` is much more powerful than e.g. C#'s `select` :-)